# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden (ASP.NET MVC 6, ASP.NET 5, IIS 7, Windows Server 2008)

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am hitting "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" after performing an XCopy deployment of an ASP.NET MVC 6 application against a Windows Server 2008 x64 running IIS 7 and trying to run the deployed web application.

I followed the steps at http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html#install-asp-net-standalone and http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#xcopy-to-iis-server and I am using dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7.

Comment: you make it sound like you failed to deploy it but I don't see how you could get this error while deploying since deployment is copying files and the error is a web request error, I think you really mean you get this error after deployment?

Comment: Joe, you are right, I edited the question, hopefully it is more accurate now.

Comment: do you have the framework installed on the server or did you deploy it with your app? Is there a web.config file in the wwwroot folder? There should a web.config be and it should have some appsettings for bootstrapping the framework, but those settings depend on the framework existing on the server. also make sure the IIS folder is configured as an application.

Comment: .NET 2, 3, 3.5, 4, and 4.5 (no 4.5.1, no 4.5.2, and no 4.6) are installed on that server. Also, dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta7 is installed via dnvm, and it is also included as part of the default packaging done by VS2015.

Comment: web.config in wwwroot contains: <add key="bootstrapper-version" value="1.0.0-beta7" /><add key="runtime-path" value="..\approot\runtimes" /><add key="dnx-version" value="1.0.0-beta7" /><add key="dnx-clr" value="clr" /><add key="dnx-app-base" value="..\approot\packages\MyApp\1.0.0\root" />, which I believe is standard stuff, it comes straight out of the packaging done by VS2015.

Comment: is it installed as a root level site or a sub folder, if sub folder did you configure it as an application? the error code is about not allowing list directory contents which typically happens if there is no default document but could also happen if the framework is not configured right or the folder not configured as an app. what happens if you try something other than root url ie use a known controller path like /Home/Index or some other known path that is expected to work? I would also check the windows application log for any clues.

Comment: Root level, I created a new web site and pointed it to the wwwroot folder, per http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html#xcopy-to-iis-server.

Comment: Did you tried executing the web.cmd in the output folder?

Comment: web.cmd works, after installing PowerShell 3.0, reinstalling DNX, and running "gci -recurse | unblock-file". Still, IIS still seems misconfigured and is not serving the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a simple test default.aspx page and got an exception that seems to indicate that ASP.NET MVC 6 only runs under **IIS 7.5 and later**. In terms of system requirements that translates to **Windows Server 2008 R2 and later**, at least at the time of writing this:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: PlatformNotSupportedException 
    Exception message: IIS 7.5 or higher is required.
   at AspNet.Loader.Error.Bootstrapper_RequiresIIS75()
   at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.LoadApplicationNet45(String appId, String appConfigPath, IProcessHostSupportFunctions supportFunctions, LoadApplicationData* pLoadAppData, Int32 loadAppDataSize, String runtimePackagePath, String appBasePath)
   at AspNet.Loader.Bootstrapper.LoadApplication(String appId, String appConfigPath, IProcessHostSupportFunctions supportFunctions, LoadApplicationData* pLoadAppData, Int32 loadAppDataSize)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ProcessHost.System.Web.Hosting.IProcessHostLite.ReportCustomLoaderError(String appId, Int32 hr, AppDomain newlyCreatedAppDomain)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

Answer (score 2):

403.14 is the error code for not being allowed to list the contents of a directory.

Are you sure that you've set the destination directory up as an application in IIS?  That seems like the most likely culprit.  Other possibilities are that your application pool is using the wrong version of .NET (something other than what's on the server), or that you've missed a folder your application needs, like App_Data or something.

Comment: It looks like IIS is trying to list the content of the directory, which is not the intended outcome.

The application pool is setup to use .NET 4.0 and is setup in Integrated Managed pipeline mode. The website is pointing to the wwwroot folder, per documentation mentioned above.

Comment: Can you add a static html file and see if you can access that? Maybe you don't have asp.net properly setup? Did you run aspnet_regiis?

Comment: Yes, IIS is trying to list the content of the directory because it can't find the proper web application.  The trick is figuring out which config issue is responsible.  If you're sure your app/directory is set up under IIS and that your server and app pool are both using .NET 4.0, then it could be that your IIS isn't registered, as opiants mentioned.  Or it could be you're missing a file -- I ran into something similar with EF where EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll wasn't put in the right place by the publish wizard, though of course xcopy is different.  Maybe turn on verbose server logging?

Comment: Static content renders fine (I just added a hello.txt file to that folder and it rendered fine). I agree, it does look like missing or incorrect configuration, I just can't figure out which one. I would expect an HTTP 500 error, not a 403.14 for most missing assemblies, files, etc. Also, ASP.NET is properly configured on the server, there are a few other ASP.NET 5, ASP.NET MVC 4 applications running just fine.

Comment: Ok. Try dropping a default.aspx file with a simple Response.Write inside it and see if that gets rendered. Also check that you have a `ExtensionlessUrl-*` handler registered in Handler Mappings.

Comment: ExtensionlessUrl-* is installed, but attempting to run a basic default.aspx page results in a "IIS 7.5 or higher is required." I cannot find any references on system requirements for ASP.NET 5/MVC 6 though...